# Instantiate object by it's path got from annotation property

Tags: java, reflection, object, path, instantiation

**1.** Have following annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Trackable {
    String builder();
}
```

**2.** usage of this annotation:

```
@Trackable(builder = "pkg1.SomeVO")
public class MyService
```

**3.** `pkg1.SomeVO` - is path to the Java object,that should be instantiated further in my aspect class.

**4.** I've got String value of `build`,that is equals to 'pkg1.SomeVO' from reflection.

The question is,how actually to instantiate `SomeVO` object?
I need to it like:
`MyBuilder mb=new SomeVO()`;
where `MyBuilder` is abstract class,already defined.

It may be any object,e. g. SomeVO2 etc.,so I definitely doesn't know in my aspect(see step 3.),what class should be instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this to get the annotation value and create the class.  Also, you may want to use the default value field and a `Class` instead of a `String` in your annotations to make things easier.

```
for (Method m : MyService.class.getDelcaredMethods())
  if (m.getAnnotation(Trackable.class) != null) {
      String className = m.getAnnotation(Trackable.class).builder()
      Class.forName(className).newInstance();
  }
```

If your class has no default constructor you need to figure out what args it takes:

```
for (Constructor c : Class.forName(className).getConstructors())
   if (c.getParameterTypes() == /* your expected arg types */)
       return c.newInstance(/* your args */);
```

To ensure your class is of a certain type (e.g. `MyBuilder`) you can make your annotation be:

```
public @interface Trackable {
   Class<? extends MyBuilder> value()
}
```

Comment: Good point,actually I missed issue about Class.Let me check it out,I will give you feedback as soon as it's possible.

Comment: The method is placed on `TYPE`, not `METHOD`.  The point is still received on my end though :)

Comment: Class.forName(className).newInstance() creates a new instance .And how can I actually use it for setting specific fields?

Comment: If you don't have a default constructor you need to invoke a constructor with args (see revised answer).  You could also call setters using reflection instead.

Comment: Garrett Hall,yes, I understand you. I mentioned, how do I know that Class.forName(className).newInstance() is SomeVO object.Because I need to instantiate it in manner:MyBuilder mb=new SomeVO(),where is MyBuilder is abstract class

Comment: You can force the Annotation value to be a subclass of MyBuilder or throw a RuntimeException if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by path, you mean the package your class is in (which is hopefully on the classpath).

```
String myClass = getClassNameFromAnnotationReflectively(); // YOU define this method...
Class<SomeVO> someVoClass = Class.forName(myClass);
SomeVO someVo = someVoClass.newInstance();
```

If your `class` doesn't have a default constructor, you can find the proper one using [`getConstructor(Class<?> ...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) (where you pass in the types of the arguments of the constructor you are looking for), and then calling [`newInstance(Object...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) on that (passing in the actual values).

There are a lot of fun methods for use on the [`Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object.  I recommend taking a look.

Comment: nicholas,I can't know,that it be SomeVO class particulary.I mean,that fist line of your code assumes,that we definitely should know,that it's SomeVO.

Comment: @sergionni,  In your question, point 4 suggests that you already have the string value of builder using reflection.  Take that `String` and use it instead of the hardcoded one from my example.